# If $MM^{'}$ is positive definite, $M$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Supposing I have a square real matrix M.
If $MM^{T}$ is positive definite,  is $M$ invertible?

I came up with the proof $MM^{T}=M\times I \times M^{T}$, that is equal to say $MM^{T}$ is congruent to an identity matrix, where $M$ is the transformation matrix. However, I couldn't prove why $M$ should be non-degenerating.  Can anyone gives me a hint on this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplication,  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55996/ata-positive-definite-then-a-is-invertible?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more general approach:

Let $(\lambda ,v)$ be an eigenpair of $M$. Since $M$ is positive definite it holds that $0<[v^TMv]_{1\times 1}$. 
Since $\color{grey}{0<}v^TMv=v^T\lambda v=\lambda \Vert v\Vert^2$, it follows that $0<\lambda $.

This proves that all eigenvalues are positive and hence not null.

Comment: Thanks Git!  Now I won't forget to use the property that all eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: @SoManyProb_for_a_broken_heart. No problem.

Answer (score 7):

$MM^T$ is positive definite $\Rightarrow (\det M)^2=\det(MM^T) >0\Rightarrow \det M\ne 0 \Rightarrow M$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you Giraffe for your help.

Comment: @SoManyProb_for_a_broken_heart.: You are welcome.