# If $AA^T$ is positive definite, is A invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

An answer to the question does exist at [If $MM^{'}$ is positive definite, $M$ is invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455772/if-mm-is-positive-definite-m-is-invertible)

However, the answer uses determinants. I was wondering if there is any other way to go about it, by showing directly that the null space of $A$ is empty?

Comment: Assuming that $A$ is square, then yes.

Comment: Maybe use rank-nullity theorem? If the kernel is trivial, the matrix is full rank and is invertible. I am not sure if the proof of rank-nullity theorem uses determinants though.

Comment: If the null space is non-trivial then $0$ is an eigenvalue so it is not positive definite.

Comment: @copper.hat Isn't $A$ necessarily square for it to make sense that $AA^T$ is positive definite?

Comment: @Filippo no ${}{}$.

Comment: Is $M$ a square matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $AA^T$ positive definite means for any nonzero $x$,

$$\left\|A^Tx\right\|^2 = x^TAA^Tx >0,$$

meaning $A^Tx$ is nonzero for all $x\neq 0$.  Therefore, $A^T$ is invertible, hence so is $A = (A^{-T})^{-T}$.

Comment: You mean "for all non-zero $x$", right?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: Is there a difference between $A^T$ and $A^{-T}$?

Comment: Oh it's the inverse of $A^T$, right?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: But why did you choose to write $A=(A^{-T})^{-T}$ instead of $A=(A^T)^T$?

Comment: I wanted to show how you would explicitly invert what you have to get what you want.  This means writing $A$ in terms of the inverse of $A^T$.

Comment: I see, thanks. As copper.hat pointed out, $A$ is not necessarely a square matrix. Your proof that the kernel of $A^t$ is zero-dimensional still works, but this doesnt mean that $A^t$ is invertible in general.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to ask if $A$ is invertible if it’s not square.

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is invertible, then $A$ is square. But it could have been the case that your proof doesn't assume that $A$ is square and in that case we could conclude that every $A$ such that $AA^T$ is positive definite is (invertible and hence) square - hence my comment :)